# Applications that can use TextMate Bundles

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

I use TextMate, and so I made a bundle recently for a language I'm working in for a class project - SPARC assembly language.  I wanted to give people in my class a copy of the bundle to make their lives easier.

Since not everyone has a Mac, let alone TextMate, I'd like to find at least one (hopefully more) viable alternatives to TextMate that are compatible with TextMate bundles.  I'm already aware of the E text editor, but if possible I'd like a few more, possibly free or open source.

And I know, TextMate is a lot more than just syntax highlighting, but there's no way everybody is going to switch to a Mac or buy TextMate just to benefit from this bundle, so I'd like to have an alternative for them.

The bundle is available at http://cl.ly/35g7 if you want it to test.  Or use.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E, as you noted. Redcar has support: http://redcareditor.com/ And apparently so does InType but I haven't been following it: http://intype.info/home/index.php

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.  Redcar is open source, so it's great for people who may not want to spend money on the others.  ;)  Anyhow, I released the bundle (what there is of it at the moment) at http://sparcasm.sourceforge.net if you happen to need a syntax highlighter for SPARC assembly language.

Answer (score 0):

E Text Editor: http://e-texteditor.com/index.html
Or Possibly Notepad++